# Form completed sent as attachment as blank

Tags: vba, excel

I designed a form in Excel for users to fill and click on submit. This should then automatically send the completed form as an attachment to a designated Outlook email address.

The problems I am encountering are

1. It sends a blank form. The form will be used by several users within the company and will be accessed from a shared drive.
2. The user cannot tell if the submit button has worked as it doesn't display any message. I would like to display a message "Your form has now been submitted"

This is the code I currently have in place

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
Dim objEmail As Object
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = "jack@jill.com"
    .Subject = "Issue Resolution Request"
    .Body = "Hi Finance Systems, please see the attached issues log for your attention"
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    .Attachment.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    .Send        ' SEND THE MESSAGE
End With

Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

ErrHandler:

End Sub
```

Comment: wouldnt it be easier just to send the forms directly to the log? You can tell vba to send the log as any file type to the destination. This would reduce email clutter and streamline the process. Further more, you can just use the email and then in a separate line have the file dumped to the preferred location, that way you no longer need the attachment. One of the macros I generated does this with XML. Want to see some sample code?

Comment: Also its worth mentioning that no where in your code do you tell the userform what to do with the user input

Answer (score 0):

try this some variation of this :)

```
 Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
 Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
 ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
 ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

 sub nameofsub()

 Dim Email As String, Subj As String
 Dim answer As Integer
 Dim Msg As String, body As String, URL As String
 Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
 Dim filelocation1 As String
 Dim wb1 as workbook

 filelocation1 = "Filepath" & "\" & "filename" & ".filextension"
 CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(filelocation1)

 'code to tell user form how to store information in the document
 'Example: (assuming you use excel as a format)
 'Set wb1 = Workbooks.open(filelocation1)
 ' wb1.worksheet.range("a1").value = textbox1.value     this might be off, double check. this might drastically differ is you use other file extensions 


 Email = "personMcDude@someaddress.com"
 Subj = "My email to you"
 body = "Hello Person," & vbCr & _
         "the stuff is in the folder" & vbCr & _
         "stuff" & vbCr & _
         "more stuff" & vbCr & _
         "and yet more" & vbCr & _
         "Thank you. "

 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

 On Error Resume Next
     With OutMail
         .To = Email
         .CC = vbNullString
         .BCC = vbNullString
         .Subject = Subj
         .body = body
         .Display
     End With
 On Error GoTo 0

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing


 End Sub
```